# Why did the contents of an another form doesn't resize along with the MainForm? (SharpDevelop)

Tags: sharpdevelop

I decided to add the Normal and Maximized FormWindowState on my MainForm in SharpDevelop but I suddenly faced a blockage. Whenever I click the Maximized, the content of an another form which is projected into the MainForm through the Panel doesn't resize along with the MainForm.
(Please refer to the image below)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeOXz.png)

I already tried anchoring it and I expected it to work but it still doesn't work. Hope someone can help me with my Problem!

Comment: It's an archived project (meaning all major development was concluded and nobody works on it). Either you train yourself to take over the development and support, or you move to another solution that's still maintained (VS or Rider), https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/issues/799